# How to replace a UIBarButtonItem with a classic UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

```
let rightBarBtn = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Light", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(rightBarBtnAction))
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarBtn
}

@objc func rightBarBtnAction(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    if theme == .dark {
        sender.title = "Dark"
        theme = .light
        Style.themeLight()
    } else {
        sender.title = "Light"
        theme = .dark
        Style.themeDark()
    }
    self.view.backgroundColor = Style.bgColor
    calenderView.changeTheme()
}
```

This was a piece of code responsible for switching between two themes in my calendar and I wanted to switch the UIBarButton to UIButton in order to change its position on screen.

This is what I came up with so far:

```
    let themeSwitch = UIButton()
    themeSwitch.setTitle("Light", for: .normal)
    themeSwitch.backgroundColor = .darkGray
    themeSwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(themeSwitchAction), for: .touchUpInside)
}

override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    calenderView.myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
}

@objc func themeSwitchAction(sender: UIButton) {
    if theme == .dark {
        sender.currentTitle = "Dark"
        theme = .light
        Style.themeLight()
    } else {
        sender.currentTitle = "light"
        theme = .dark
        Style.themeDark()
    }
    self.view.backgroundColor = Style.bgColor
    calenderView.changeTheme()
}
```

As you can probably tell, this doesn't work. Can someone please show me the way to do this correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand from your explanation, if you want to change the position of the button from right to left or from left to right; no need to use `**UIButton**`.

You can simply assign the button to `**self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem**`

But anyway, you can add a `**UIButton**` inside `**UIBarButtonItem**` as you see below:
[image: Adding UIButton inside UIBarButtonItem]

Hope that helps.